# xml and external swf documents

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

My XML scripts work fine in the local swf. If I load an external swf, can I still retrieve XML data from the same way. **What problems will I encounter with XML and externally loaded swf files?**

Based on looking at my sample code, some response about XML problems would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

**VARIABLE TYPES**

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);
var myString:String = "";
var count:int = 0;
var myStg:String = "";
var fcount:int = 0;
```

**RUBY REXML**

```
msg1 = {"msg" => {"head" => {"type"  => "frctl", "seq_no" => seq_no, "version" => 1.0},
       "SESSION" => {"text" => "88888", "timer" => -1000,
       "count" => 10, "fcount" => "10"}}}
```

**XML**

```
<msg>
  <head>
    <seq_no>10000001</seq_no>
    <type>frctl</type>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </head>
  <body>
    <fcount>10</fcount>
    <timer>-1000</timer>
    <count>10</count>
    <file>svrReadyXML.swf</file>
  </body>
</msg>
```

Comment: Again I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you wondering if a swf file that's been loaded into another swf file can access XML data? That is of course possible, simply by coding the swf that you'll load so that it loads some XML, then making sure the XML file is in the right place for when that swf is loaded into the other swf.. Sounds convoluted, but that's straightforward. But is that what you're asking?

Comment: What problems will I encounter with XML and externally loaded swf files?

Comment: This is part of what I'm talking about in relation to the way you ask questions. For the first part, 'XML' and 'externally loaded swf files' are two separate things which don't directly relate to each other (though they *can* relate to each other), and so you can't just ask what problems you'll have when using those two things, it's **way** too broad. Secondly, asking for what problems you might have with any given thing you want to do is probably too broad. You need to go and *do* something, encounter a problem, and solve it (perhaps by asking here), that's how you'll learn I think.

Comment: @debu is absolutely right. The way you phrase your questions leads me (and possibly others) to believe you haven't even tried to do what it is you're asking about. So, have you tried to do what it is your asking?

Comment: Absolutely agree! I see a pattern with my documentation I need to change, but unfortunatly this question was hatched too soon. Look for better posts soon.:)

Answer (score 0):

**Converting Integers and string literals will be an issue**

It sounds like you need to make some smaller steps first. Also, I recommend some advanced study books to help formulate a more specific question. Each book has chapters on XML and sockets. **I wish there were more specific examples.**

Essential ActionScript 3.0
Colin Moock

ActionScript 3.0 Cookbook
Joey Lott, Darron Schall, Keith Peters

ActionScript 3.0 Bible
Roger Braunstein, Mims H. Wright, Joshua J. Noble

Comment: I think my mind might be about to fall over. You're answering your own question, and referring to yourself as 'you'? *"It sounds like you need to make some smaller steps first."*. What the..?